# Given any power of 2, there exist infinitely many powers of 2 whose decimal representation ends with the digits of the given power of 2.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have got a question  that  I am not able to understand how to solve it? .

Given any power of 2 (such as 1024), there exist infintely many powers of 2 whose decimal representation ends with the digits of the given power of 2.

How to prove this? Could anybody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given integer $m>0$, you are trying to find infinitely many different integers $n>0$ such that $2^m\equiv 2^n \pmod{10^m}$.  This condition is equivalent to $1\equiv 2^{n-m} \pmod{5^m}$. If some power of $2$ were congruent to $1$ modulo $5^m$, that would help...

Comment: I need little more explanation. If you could help me I would be thankful to you. How could we say that here we are trying to find integer n such that $2^m\equiv 2^n \pmod{10^m}$?

Comment: AN observation : $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod 5^n$ for integer $n>0$ $$\implies ord_{(5^n)}2=\phi(5^n)=4\cdot5^{n-1},$$ so $4\cdot5^{n-1}$ has to divide $(n-m)$

Comment: Taking a number mod $10^m$ extracts the last $m$ digits.