# Is there a pandigital perfect power $p^k$ for any prime $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation, decimal-expansion

A number is [*pandigital*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandigital_number) in base 10 if it contains all the digits from $0$ to $9$ in its decimal representation. For example, $541672390489$ is pandigital.

My question is, given a prime $p$, does there exist a positive integer $k$ such that $p^k$ is pandigital? For $p=2$, [WolframAlpha tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E121) that $2^{121}$ is pandigital. In fact, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367475/given-any-power-of-2-there-exist-infinitely-many-powers-of-2-whose-decimal-repr) allows us to conclude that there are infinitely many $k$ such that $2^k$ is pandigital.

Originally, I was investigating if for a given prime $p$, there was a $k$ such that $p^k$ contained a certain decimal digit. I found [How to prove that all primes $p$ will have a power $p^k$ with a $2$ in its decimal representation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721985/how-to-prove-that-all-primes-p-will-have-a-power-pk-with-a-2-in-its-decim?rq=1) , and experimenting with smaller cases led me to believe that this generalised form is true.

I found some questions asking to prove that for any finite sequence of digits there's a power of $2$ that starts with that sequence, though I couldn't find anything similar generalizing to all primes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For every prime $p$, if there exists one pandigital power of $p$, say $p^k$, then we will have infinitely many pandigital powers as we have infinitely many $n$ such that:
$$p^n \equiv p^k \pmod{10^{{\lceil{\log (p^k)}}\rceil}}$$
Thus, for a given prime $p$, it suffices to show that there exists one pandigital power  of $p$, to generate infinitely many of them. This can be done in a very nifty maner. Say we have a few of the base-10 representation digits in $p$  (for the sake of example, let us say $p$ has $6$ distinct digits and $17$ digits overall). Now, let $$p^d \equiv 1 \pmod{10^{17}}$$
Now, every $p^{kd+1} \equiv p \pmod{10^{10}}$ will have the $6$ distinct digits in addition to extra digits in the left. However, we know that we can use bounding to control the leading digits of any $a^k$. So, we set $a=p^d$. This gives us control over the first few digits of $p^{kd}$. Say we require a $2$ in the decimal representation. We can find some value $s$ such tha:
$$10^ls<p^{kd}<10^l(s+1)$$
where $s$ is going to be the starting of the decimal expansion of $p^{kd}$. Then, we have:
$$10^lsp<p^{kd+1}<10^l(s+1)p$$
So, all we need to do is find $s$ such that $2 \cdot 10^m<sp<(s+1)p<3 \cdot 10^m$ which is trivial. We can now continue this process for the other $2$ distinct digits if not obtained already.

Example, let $p=7$. First, we need a $1$. We have $7$ already and $7^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{10^1}$. So, we are looking for some $7^{4k+1}$ starting with $1$. As we need $10^m < 7s < 8s < 2 \cdot 10^m$, we can use $s=2$. Now, we can set $s=2$ as the starting of $7^{4k}=2401^k$, which happens for $k=1$. Thus, we have:
$$7^{4k+1}=7^5=16807$$
which preserves the $7$ at the end as well as acquires a few new digits. We can repeat this process till we acquire a pandigital power of $7$.

Comment: Disclaimer: The process above is not efficient but does the job. For example, if we have to continue after $16807$, the number gets really large (but the job would have most probably been done by then since the number would have so many digits)

Comment: Why is there a $d$ such that $p^d\equiv 1 \mod (10^{17})$? Are you assuming $p\neq 5$, $p\neq 2$?

Comment: $p=2$ and $p=5$ are cases where you can just check and find a pandigital number. This suffices to show that there are infinitely many powers of $2$ and $5$ which are pandigital as there would be infinitely many powers of them ending with that decimal string. For $p \neq 5 , p \neq 2$, we have $p^d \equiv 1 \pmod{10^m}$ since $\gcd(p,10)=1$, by using Euler's Totient Theorem and order.

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively, for any number $p$ not of the form $10^m$ we would expect that there is some $N$ so that for all $k \ge N, p^k$ is pandigital.  The idea is that $p^k$ has lots of digits and it is hard for all those digits to miss any particular value.  This is hard to prove, however.

The proof that there are infinitely many $p^k$ that are pandigital is easy for any particular $p$.  The proof you cite for powers of $2$ starting with any digit string carries over to any base (except powers of $10$), so find powers of $p$ that start with $1234567890$ and you are done.