# Pandigital Generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

While doing calculations with large integers in python, I found something I thought was interesting.  Looking at small bases, I've noticed that if I keep raising the base to a higher power, I eventually find a pandigital number.  Several examples are listed below:

$$2^{68} = 295147905179352825856,$$
$$278^{8} = 35674538806191022336.$$

Trying this for a few bases less than 1000, it seems that the first pandigital number is never exceptionally large.  For larger bases, it seems that a smaller exponent is required to get the first pandigital.  I haven't taken these experiment very far, so don't take my word for it.

My question is, can we prove/disprove that this process will always generate a pandigital?  In other words, if I take any number $b$ as a base, does there exist an exponent $e$ such that $b^e$ is pandigital?  I think the answer is yes.  My reasoning so far is that if we multiply a number $b*n \leftarrow n$, every digit of the previous iteration, $n$ will be changed and possibly we will introduce another digit to $n$.  So, intuitively, it seems that if our power will eventually have enough digits to guarantee that every digit from 0 to 9 is included.  The problem I'm having is that I cannot see a pattern in how each digit changes.  For example, if we look at the units digit of a power, there will always be a cycle.  The units digit of $2^n$ cycles mod 10 over $(4,8,6,2)$.  But, the 10s digit does not appear to have any pattern, and I do not know if eventually every digit appears in the 10s place.  I'm not expecting an answer, but perhaps some advice on how to get traction on this problem.  Thanks.

Comment: One of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491752/is-there-a-pandigital-perfect-power-pk-for-any-prime-p) describes a process to successively accumulate diverse digits along a sequence of powers of a prime.  Presumably, this method could be adapted to the composite base case with some (not necessarily easy) details.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks